# Render to cshtml and get logged in ID

Tags: html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am very new to angularjs..I have developed demo app of login..I tried to render page if login id and password are correct but it doesnot render

**Code:**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.submit = function () {
        if ($scope.username && $scope.password) {
            var user = $scope.username;
            var pass = $scope.password;

            $http.get('/angularjs/welcome'); //<--> I want to render to welcome.cshtml page
```

How to render to cshtml page and also get id to cshtml page?

Comment: use `document.location = "PathToTheFile"` or `window.location = "PathToTheFile"` instead of `$http.get`.

Also you can use `window.open("PathToTheFile","_self")`

Comment: @KunalKakkad I tried that also but getting error of `The resource cannot be found.` also tried `$window.location.href` but same error.I gave path `Views/angularjs/welcome.cshtml`

Comment: can you please just fiddle the stuff to have analyse it properly.

Comment: @KunalKakkad I tried to make a jsfiddle but its not giving even user table but you may get where is actual problem of rendering..here it is https://jsfiddle.net/BDhara/tfxn5yg5/

Comment: @KunalKakkad please check http://plnkr.co/edit/poS2LzPY1dfDsnvPxbMv?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try this.

Please create the Action Method in Controller to render the welcome page.

```
public ActionResult Welcome()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

then update the script as below:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function ($scope, $window) {
    $scope.submit = function () {
        if ($scope.username && $scope.password) {
            var user = $scope.username;
            var pass = $scope.password;
            $window.location.href = 'Employee/Welcome';
        }
    }
}]);
```

Please try and let me know if any issue.

Comment: getting error of `ReferenceError: $window is not defined at r.$scope.submit`

Comment: Please update '$http' with '$window' in your script.

Comment: still getting error of `The resource cannot be found.`

Comment: Now this error is something related to the path of the redirected page.Might be page not available at the location.

Comment: this is cshtml not html..may be it need controller to render..do you know how to do that?

Comment: ahan thanx first question is solved now How I can get loggedin user name in welcome page?

Comment: Please try "System.Web.Httpcontext.Current.User.Identity.Name" to get the logged-in user name in welcome page.